# Spring @GetMapping without using every getter in the bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean, `ProfileStandardSection`, with overloaded constructors. I have a getter for each object in the bean, but not all constructors use every object. When I use the bean in my controller, the objects that aren't intended to be used still show up in the JSON object.

Can I have it... not do that?

My bean:

```
public class ProfileStandardSection {

    private List<ProfileStandardRow> summandRows;
    private List<ProfileStandardRow> topFive;
    private final ProfileStandardRow totalRow;
    private ProfileStandardRow pctOfSuperTotal;

    public ProfileStandardSection(List<ProfileStandardRow> summandRows, ProfileStandardRow totalRow, ProfileStandardRow pctOfSuperTotal) {
        this.summandRows = summandRows;
        this.totalRow = totalRow;
        this.pctOfSuperTotal = pctOfSuperTotal;
    }

    public ProfileStandardSection(List<ProfileStandardRow> topFive, ProfileStandardRow totalRow) {
        this.topFive = topFive;
        this.totalRow = totalRow;
    }

    public List<ProfileStandardRow> getSummandRows() {
        return summandRows;
    }
    
    public List<ProfileStandardRow> getTopFive() {
        return topFive;
    }

    public ProfileStandardRow getTotalRow() {
        return totalRow;
    }

    public ProfileStandardRow getPctOfSuperTotal() {
        return pctOfSuperTotal;
    }
}
```

My controller calling the bean:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${api-setting.cors-allowed-origin}"})
@RestController
public class ProfileController {
    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepository profileRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/liabilities/{company}/{year}")
    public ProfileStandardSection getLiabilitiesSection(@PathVariable int company, @PathVariable int year) {
        Optional<ProfileStandardRow> totalRow = profileRepository.findById(
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.TOTAL_LIABILITIES.getRowkey()));

        List<ProfileStandardRow> topFive = profileRepository.findAllById(Arrays.asList(
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.FIRST_HIGHEST_LIABILITY.getRowkey()),
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.SECOND_HIGHEST_LIABILITY.getRowkey()),
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.THIRD_HIGHEST_LIABILITY.getRowkey()),
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.FOURTH_HIGHEST_LIABILITY.getRowkey()),
                new RowId(company, year, RowInfo.FIFTH_HIGHEST_LIABILITY.getRowkey())));

        return new ProfileStandardSection(topFive, totalRow.get());
    }
}
```

The JSON object I get back:

```
{
"summandRows": null,
"topFive": [...stuff I want...],
"totalRow": {...stuff I want...},
"pctOfSuperTotal": null
}
```

Is there a way to configure this so that it doesn't include the `summandRows` and `pctOfSuperTotal` objects in the JSON?

I know it's including them because there are getters for them in the bean which are just getting used cuz Spring things, and IntelliJ doesn't even realize it. So it's marking them as unused. So is there a way to tell Spring which getters to use?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring but with Jackson. So no there is no way to tell Spring which to use as it isn't Spring related (the fact that you use Spring doesn't make everything a Spring problem!). You can tell Jackson to ignore null values (which by default are exposed) by adding `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on the class, or bij configuring this on the `ObjectMapper` in use.

Comment: @M.Deinum lol I'm not trying to attack or disparage Spring here, but noted. Thanks for letting me know. The ignore null function won't work tho. Sometimes the things that do need to be included will actually have null values.

Answer (score 0):

try using  @jsonIgnore  example

```
public class ProfileStandardSection { 
 @JsonIgnore  
private final ProfileStandardRow totalRow;
// rest of the property same
}
```